# Sending get request with parameters in React to Java Backend but showing No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, reactjs, servlets, jdbc, cors

I am trying to send a get request with 2 parameters page and limit to the Java Backend Server and it is showing the following error:-
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/BatchDisplay.do?page={page}&limit={count}' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

My React Code:-

```
const getLatestJSPost = () => {
const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/BatchDisplay.do?page={page}&limit={count}";
axios(API_URL)
.then((response) => response.data)
.then((data) => {
            setData((prev) => [...prev, ...data]);
            size=data.sizevalue;
            setHasMore(true);
})
};
```

My Web.xml file in java:-

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
  <param-value>http://localhost:3000</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>BatchDisplay</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.School.BatchDisplay</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>BatchDisplay</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/BatchDisplay.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while back. In your `Web.config` file put this in `<system.webServer>`

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```